# Jest/React/Redux error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant? Action: {}

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, action, jestjs

This error is haunting me for a while no matter how I try to write my tests for actions, it gives me this:

**"Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant? Action: {}
"**

but if I console log that action I'm trying to test, it prints out type which is defined as it should be. 
I'm using jest framework for testing react/redux app.

Here is the action I was testing:

```
  export const updateUserGenderAction = (valueToUpdate) => {
  return (dispatch) => Promise.all([
    patchUpdateGender(valueToUpdate).then((response) => {
      dispatch(getSuccessData(response, 'GET_USER_DATA'))
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(getErrorData(error, 'GET_USER_ERROR'))
    })
  ])
}
```

action creators:

```
export function getSuccessData (response, actionType) {
  return {
    payload: response,
    type: actionType
  }
}

export function getErrorData (err, errorType) {
  Alert.error(err)
  return {
    payload: err,
    type: errorType
  }
}
```

and test attempts:

```
  it('creates updateUserGender action', () => {
    console.log(actions.updateUserGenderAction())
    const expectedActions = [
            { type: 'GET_USER_DATA', payload: userData },
            { type: 'GET_USER_ERROR', payload: userData }
    ]
    return store.dispatch(actions.updateUserGenderAction()).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
    })
  })


  it('calls updateUserGenderAction', async () => {
    actions.updateUserGenderAction = jest.fn(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(getSuccessData(response, 'GET_USER_DATA'))
    })

    let mockStore = configureMockStore()
    let store = mockStore({})
    await store.dispatch(getSuccessData())

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(getSuccessData(response, 'GET_USER_DATA'))

  })
```

and console.log(actions.updateUserGenderAction()) :

> Promise {
>         { payload: 
>          { getUserDataAction: [Function: getUserDataAction],
>            updateUserGenderAction: [Object],
>            updateFirstNameAction: [Function: updateFirstNameAction],
>            updateLastNameAction: [Function: updateLastNameAction],
>            updateMiddleNameAction: [Function: updateMiddleNameAction],
>            updateCountryAction: [Function: updateCountryAction],
>            changePasswordAction: [Function: changePasswordAction],
>            updatePrimaryEmailAction: [Function: updatePrimaryEmailAction],
>            updateUsernameAction: [Function: updateUsernameAction],
>            updateChangeAlternateEmailAction: [Function: updateChangeAlternateEmailAction],
>            updateAddPhoneAction: [Function: updateAddPhoneAction],
>            updateEditPhoneAction: [Function: updateEditPhoneAction],
>            getUserSessionAction: [Function: getUserSessionAction],
>            deleteUserSessionAction: [Function: deleteUserSessionAction],
>            updateDefaultMailingAddressAction: [Function: updateDefaultMailingAddressAction],
>            deleteMailingAddressAction: [Function: deleteMailingAddressAction],
>            addMailingAddressAction: [Function: addMailingAddressAction],
>            editMailingAddressAction: [Function: editMailingAddressAction],
>            getSuccessData: [Function: getSuccessData],
>            getErrorData: [Function: getErrorData] },
>         type: 'GET_USER_DATA' } }

Does anyone know what I might be missing and how to test these kind of actions properly?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `getSuccessData()` with no arguments, so `actionType` is undefined:

```
export function getSuccessData(response, actionType) {
  return {
    payload: response,
    type: actionType // `actionType` is undefined
  }
}
```

[Types should typically be defined as string constants](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html), so it would be better to specify it in the action creator:

```
const GET_USER_DATA = 'GET_USER_DATA';

export function getSuccessData(response) {
  return {
    type: GET_USER_DATA,
    payload: response,
  }
}
```

See also: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html

Comment: Thank you, I changed them to constants but it didn't solve the issue, still getting the same error.